# Issue with elements other than background with jquery_interactive_bg.js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to get a parallax effect on my website's landing page. I used the [interactive_bg.js](https://github.com/peachananr/interactive_bg) plugin and working backwards from the [demo tutorial](https://onextrapixel.com/create-an-interactive-moving-backgroundobject-that-reacts-to-viewers-cursor/) I was finally able to get the picture I want with the desired effect.

This is my current HTML -

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper bg" data-ibg-bg="pics/Q.jpg">
      <div class="main">
          <h1>I am<span id="typed"></span></h1>
          <h4 id="test">I create<span id="typed2"></span></h4>
          <a id="but1" class="ghost-button-semi-transparent" href="#">Check me out!</a>
    </div>
  </div>  
</body>
```

Here's my CSS-

```
  html {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .wrapper {
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .main {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .bg {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
  }

  .ibg-bg {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .main {
    position: relative;
  }
```

Now the `wrapper bg` div is the one with the background. Anything I put after that div either comes under it or if I use relative positioning comes on top of it. If I add margins to pull it down it screws up my page when the window size is changed.

How do I put elements after the `wrapper bg` div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question, you want to put something after div with class wrapper bg.
This div has position:absolute, so if you set it's position relative, this div remains on the top of the page (with height 100%) and, if you add a new div, it will positioning after the wrapper div as you want

Comment: Changing the wrapper div's position messes up the interactive_bg.js plugin. It only works on absolute position

Comment: Uhmmm, i took the example from github and this solution for me work, even the script with the background animation

Comment: I love you. That's all I can say

Answer (score 1):

change position: absolute; to position: relative;

Remove body height 100%;

.wrapper set height of your need.

```
.bg {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'open sans';
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    height: auto !important;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I need the height to be 100% only.. Setting the position to relative, however, fixed the issue.